# Django translate data from the DB {{ profession }}

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-translated-fields

Is it possible to translate DB entries? I have a dependent dropdown story that i need to translate. But i cant translate the dropdown fields, the fields come from other models and har hard coded. I can use HTML with JQ to achive this but i want to skip the manual labor to update the forms  everytime new profession or professioncategories are added.

```
class Profession(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30),

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Professioncategory(models.Model):
    profession = models.ForeignKey(Profession, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Skills(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(_('Active'), default=True)
    profession = models.ForeignKey(Profession, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    professioncategory = models.ForeignKey(Professioncategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    posted_on = models.DateTimeField(_('Registrerad'), auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(_('last updated'), auto_now=True)
    years_of_exp = models.CharField(_('years of experiance'), max_length=20, choices=YEARS_OF_EXP, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Do you mean translation to other languages?

Comment: I have already implemented the translation by using i18n and everythin is working. But how do i translate database entries. I can translate using {% trans ""%}  but how do i translate the inputs from a model like  {{ profession.name }} i use this value in a dropdown field in a form

Comment: There are some packages helping to achieve this. They produce additional columns or tables for translations.

Comment: Do you have tips, whats the name of these packages? thx

Comment: Such questions (recommend me a lib/book/site) a considered offtopic on SO. Please use search. There is `django-translations` for example.